# Iterate through the columns of a Datagrid's ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid that needs to hide certain columns right after its data-bound. Here's my code so far:

```
private IEnumerable<DataGridColumn> GetDataGridColumns(DataGrid grid)
{
    var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;

    if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;

    foreach (var item in itemsSource)
    {
        var column = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridColumn;
        if (null != column) yield return column;
    }
}

private void LoadData()
{
    GridMain.ItemsSource = (new VTAEEntities()).OrganizationInterfaces.ToList();

    foreach (DataGridColumn Column in GetDataGridColumns(GridMain))
    {
        // Hiding columns
        if (Column.Header as String != null) {
            String tempHeader = Column.Header as String;

            String[] unrequiredColumns = new String[] { 
                "Instances",
                "Interfaces",
                "Organizations",
                "RegisteredCallerOnly"
            };

            if (unrequiredColumns.Contains(tempHeader)) {
                Column.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }

        // Read-only columns
        if (Column.Header as String != null)
        {
            String tempHeader = Column.Header as String;

            String[] unrequiredColumns = new String[] { 
                "InstanceId",
                "InterfaceId",
                "OrganizationId"
            };

            if (unrequiredColumns.Contains(tempHeader))
            {
                Column.IsReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the unwanted columns + the columns I want to be read only are all there. Upon debugging, I realize that the GridMain.Columns is always 0 count. How do I iterate through the columns in an ItemSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide column than you can make use of

```
AutoGeneratingColumn
```

event of wpf grid that will might work for you to hide column.

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
      DataGridBoundColumn col = e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
     //set visiblity by doing the code you wnat ..i.logic to hide column
      if (col.Header.ToString().ToLower() == "id") 
        { 
            col.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }
}
```

Comment: `AutoGeneratingColumn` event seems to be the way to go. I'll try.

Comment: Will do. I was out of office away from my keyboard... still am :(

Answer (score 2):

wow, I think you're off road here.

the Itemcontainer is actually the Row in a WPF DG, not the column.

but you can achieve what you want a lot more easily:

```
foreach (var Column in GridMain.Columns)
{
    // ...
}
```

also, I recommend you use Visibility.Collapsed instead of Visibility.Hidden in your case (otherwise the space will still be reserved)

as to why your Columns.Count = 0, I guess it is because when you actually run this code, your DG has not been rendered by WPF yet. So I would throw a GridMain.UpdateLayout() before looping through the Datagrid's Columns.

It might not be enough though. In this case you'd have to use this code:

```
UpdateLayout();
Action emptyDelegate = delegate() { };
Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render, emptyDelegate);
```

(to force an update)

otherwise, I suggest either you hide the columns on the fly using the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event handler in the DG, or you do the hiding AFTER the DG has been rendered using the DG's `Loaded` event

Comment: Coming from a Windows Desktop application background... I find myself trembling at WPF... Good suggestions. I'll try and return with results.